# How to print lines from a file with multiple conditions in Python?

Tags: python, file, line, conditional-statements

I got a short question regarding python:
How to do read specific lines from a file?
By using multiple filters, bellow is my current code that doesn't show the expected results for me:

```
for line in loglist:
    if (str('send') and str('packet')) in line:
        print line
```

So, what I want is to print lines that contains both the words "send" and "packet",
but it prints all lines that contain either send or packet.

many thanks in advance guys,

Comment: If you try the (str()..and..str()) expression in python shell, you recognize, that the result is "packet" alone, i.e. the last term due to the and operation enforcing evaluation of all terms. My intuitive approach would be a regular expression match, but even if this might be faster, it doesn't look prettier than the solution in the answer given, especially if the words may occur in any order.

Answer (score 3):

One way:

```
if all( x in line for x in ('send','packet')):
```

This is the most efficient way to do it if you need to scale up to an arbitrary number of conditions ...

Another way:

```
if ('send' in line) and ('packet' in line):
```

With just 2 checks, this is likely to be faster than the above.

Answer (score 3):

You should separate your conditions: -

```
if ('send' in line) and ('packet' in line):
    print line
```

**If you do: -**

```
if (str('send') and str('packet')) in line:
```

It is similar to saying: -

```
if 'packet' in line:
```

Because, the inner condition is `and` which **returns the `last` false value**, or **if all are True, then returns the last value.**

So, `str('send') and str('packet')` is equivalent to `'packet'`

And you don't need that `str` wrapping around them.

Answer (score 0):

`(str('send') and str('packet'))`

Evaluates to "packet" with is always true (not what you want). Try

`if "send" in line and "packet" in line`

Comment: It evaluates to `'packet'`, not to true.

Comment: hmmm, sure enough. guess i'm not as think as i smart i am.

Answer (score -1):

`(str('send') and str('packet'))` evaluates to `True`. So you are saying `True in line`, which doesn't work of course. What you need is

```
if 'send' in line and 'packet' in line):
    print line
```

BTW, it makes no sense to run `str()` on a string, why would you convert a string to a string?

Comment: No, it evaluates to `'send'`.

Comment: @glglgl. I thought it evaluates to `'packet'`, which is the last true value.